How to test deploy your google apps script editor add-on
I am trying to run test deployment for my editor add on created. The addOn creates a menu on the top and on click of it sidebar opens on the side panel. This is my appsscript.json file
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING",
    "access": "ANYONE"
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  ]
} 

I am using this link to setup test deployment Test an Editor Add-on
The Authorization state I have used both Auth.none and Auth.limited. When I click on execute, google slides open in different editor. However when I click on the navmenu it gives me error

Exception: Specified permissions are not sufficient to call Ui.showSidebar. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui

Usually when you run for the first time ,app asks for permissions, however while testing, it is not asking for any permissions at all. Any solutions?
